# How can I stop url rewriting after I redirect using mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How can I stop after I hit the first successful rule when working with `mod_rewrite`?

I've tried using different combinations of the `L` and `E` flags but have not yet been able to find a way to do this.

Here is my current `.htaccess` file with my latest attempt

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(basket|order).html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,E=STOP:1]
RewriteCond %{ENV:STOP} !1
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(basket|order).html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,E=STOP:1]
RewriteCond %{ENV:STOP} !1
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ cms.php?pagename=$1 [QSA]
RewriteCond %{ENV:STOP} !1
RewriteRule ^$ cms.php [QSA]
```

Every time I try to open `http://www.example.com/basket.html`, for example, it redirects me to `http://www.example.com/cms.php?pagename=basket`. But this isn't right, I'm only trying to redirect from `http` to `https`.

Comment: Without using the ENV stuff, the L flag stops for me andI don't get redirected to cms.php

Comment: @JonLin This would be great, but doesn't work! Stil the same http://www.example.com/basket.html -> http://www.example.com/cms.php?pagename=basket instead of https.

Comment: I've reworded a bit of your post (and the title) to make it more clear what you are asking for.

Comment: @KevinBrown Ok, thanks a lot - my english is not the best! ;)

Comment: Just as a sanity check, you *are* clearing your browser's cache after each time you've changed your htaccess file, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules as this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(basket|order)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(basket|order)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^$ cms.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ cms.php?pagename=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Used `THE_REQUEST` instead of `REQUEST_URI` as your last rule is routing `.html` requests to `cms.php` thus changing value of `REQUEST_URI` whereas `THE_REQUEST` remains unchanged.